# HTML5 Canvas BezierTo smearing

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, bezier

I have an HTML 5 canvas, and on it I'm using a BezierTo stroke.

When moving the mouse/target clockwise, I run in to a "smearing" problem. Doing the same thing counterclockwise causes no problem.

I can't figure out why I'm getting a fill type effect rather than a line. Noone else seems to have had this problem.

The code for the curve is:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "#D43";
ctx.lineWidth = 8 * scale;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(379 * scale, 473 * scale);

var xDif = 379 - redProbeX ;
var yDif = 473 - redProbeY ;

ctx.bezierCurveTo( 
    (379 - xDif / 3 + 38 ) * scale, ( 473 - yDif * 2 / 5 + 250) * scale,
    (379 - xDif * 3 / 5 + 38 ) * scale, ( 473 - yDif * 2 / 3 + 250) * scale,
    (redProbeX + 38 * scale ) , (redProbeY + 250 * scale) );
ctx.stroke();
```

You can see the smearing in this video: http://aaronkuchma.ca/bezierToSmear.mp4

The canvas usually redraws smoothly; however it was lagging when CamStudio was capturing the video. That's a problem for me to deal with at another time.

Comment: It looks like you are not deleting the strokes properly before you draw new ones. That problem seems to be outside of the code you posted.

Comment: don't forget to use closePath, also. (before or after the stroke), otherwise paths will pile and slow down the display in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
```

at the top of your code and it should work.